# Needed Stylistic Animation Advice

Tags: animation

I am working on making an animated short that I have been wanting to do for a while (at last!). I wanna make sure I am doing the best practices and not making it unnecessarily difficult for myself. Below I put together a animation demo reel of my first attempts at getting the style of the animation down. The problem is that it feels like I am doing something wrong with having to manually put a keyframe for the viewport and renders and it is easy to mess up. Is there a keymap shortcut for this? The way I have the character currently is without a rig, just a hierarchy of objects parented with empty containers that hold the objects(There is a screenshot of this as well below). Once I actually scale up the scene and have other characters I think it would become unmanageable quite fast. Anything helps thank you!

Here is the animated demo reel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdUbZy44-ic

Comment: Hello, could you please reformulate your question because it's hard to understand, for example you say " Is there a keymap shortcut for this?", is it your question, and what is "this"? You can create a parent-child hierarchy that you can animate, another way is to create an armature and parent the parts of your object to the bones